# Lodash + TypeScript _.property iteratee shorthand

Tags: typescript, lodash

Is it possible to use _.property iteratee shorthand somehow with TypeScript?

Consider the following example. How can you make it compile?

```
let someCollection: Type1[] = [obj1, obj2];
let result: Type2[] = _(someCollection).filter('some.nested.property').map('another.nested.property');
```

How do you do it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be shortest solution:

```
let result: Type2[] = _(someCollection).filter('some.nested.property').map <Type2> ('another.nested.property');
```

By explicitly giving the Type in <> the compiler is satisfied (`<Type2>`). Of course you're only really type safe if your expectations regarding the path 'another.nested.property' really yield objects of Type2, i.e. changing the _.property string later to something different (like 'another.thing.that.is.different') the compiler still thinks everything is ok, while in reality your code will break when running it.